# How do I load a collection in a model then query it with the query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have create a morphMany relationship for ratings and I'm having a problem loading the ratings relationship data inside the model using the model->load or model::with method both of them aren't letting me use the collections model builder.

if I do this inside a method of a model it throws an error:

```
$all = this->ratings()->get(); 
return $all;
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::ratingInfo()
```

I need the ratings query builder so I can then query and filter the results but It's not using the query builder and even if I make this a scope it's still throws the same error.

all code:

```
class Product extends Model 
{    
    use Rateable;

    protected $table = "products";

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',   
        'sku', 
        'quantity', 
        'unit_price', 
        'created_by', 'updated_by'
    ];

    public function created_by() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'created_by', 'id');
    }

    public function updated_by() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'updated_by', 'id');
    }    

    public function ratings() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Rating', 'rateable');
    }

    public function ratingInfo() {
        $all = $this->ratings()->get() error using get request for eager loading;          

        // i want to query like this
        $two_star = $all->filter(function ($item, $key) {
            return $item->rating === 2;
        });
        return $all;
    }
}


public function show($id) {
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    // it doesn't seem to matter if use the keyword ::with('ratingInfo')
    $product->load('ratingInfo', 'created_by', 'updated_by');  

    return response()->json($product, 200, ['Content-Length' => strlen(json_encode($product))]);
}



class Rating extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ratings';

    protected $fillable = ['rating', 'comment', 'user_id', 'rateable_id', 'rateable_type'];   

    public function rating()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using phone numbers and user and companies as an example:

```
class PhoneNumber extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning callable models.
     */
    public function callable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the model's phone numbers.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function phoneNumbers()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(PhoneNumber::class, 'callable');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the model's phone numbers.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function phoneNumbers()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(PhoneNumber::class, 'callable');
    }
}
```

To save a phone number to a user or company would be like this:

```
$phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber(['number' => '555-555-5555']);
$user->phoneNumbers()->save(phoneNumber);

$phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber(['number' => '555-555-5555']);
$company->phoneNumbers()->save(new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber));
```

Then to access the phone number collections associated with each, simply:

```
$user->phoneNumbers  // this is a Collection
$company->phoneNumbers  // this is a Collection

$user->phoneNumbers->count() // access to all Collection methods as this point
```

Comment: I'm doing this as a method inside a model and this is the error I'm getting Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.

Comment: Try my example, the problem is you're treating ratings as a method, don't use parentheses  - () - to retrieve the ratings collection

Comment: Method addEagerConstraints does not exist. I reckon it has to do with using the with statement or load method on the show function

Comment: Have you ever done this I haven't and I can't see why this is happening it's always Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.

Comment: Yes I use polymophic models in a number of my work projects, let me look over your question and see if there is anything odd.

Comment: I'm using a Rateable Trait and that creates my ratings fine in my table seeder

Comment: biggest thing that stood out was the method name on your ratings model, i changes that to rateable()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146815/discussion-between-onyx-and-btl).